# users names not showing in users view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone tell me why the email addresses are not showing in the users list view below?

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Users</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        **<td><%= user.email %></td>**
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
```

Comment: Do they really have a _non-null_ email value?

Comment: they are in the DB just not showing on the hmtl.erb view page. this is copy txt from the page in browser - Users
Email 
Show Edit Destroy
Show Edit Destroy
Show Edit Destroy
Show Edit Destroy
Show Edit Destroy
New User

Comment: are those `**` surrounding the td elements actually there? or you only put that on the question to mark the td with the problem? maybe it's messing the markup

Comment: Doesn't seems to find any mistake in the code (I ignore those *), only one thing might happen, that email user is blank but since you said it's really in the db, can you please change `user.email` to `user.id` and see the result because `id` is always sure exist in the record.

Comment: Will have a go and see what it throws out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with seeing the two asterisks around the  element. I'm thinking that might be messing something up. If you want to bold the user's email you could try something like `<td><b><%= user.email %></b></td>`.

Are you getting any errors anywhere?

If the asterisks are just there to help us see the line of code, and you say that you see the users (and their emails) in the db, I think it could be one of two other relatively minor things.

1. Whats your controller look like for this view? Are you passing @users to this view? You could try just dumping @users on the page to make sure that it's available.
2. Is the field on your User model that holds the email called `email`?

Comment: One supposes OP is using the asterisks to emphasize the offending line in their code for our benefit, and that they are not part of the actual code.